# While passing 2d matrix using double pointer to print function it printing last element of matrix zero

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

Here is simple code just reading two matrix one is 3*3 dimensional and other is 3*1 dimensional. while printing first matrix A[3][3] the last element of matrix is printing zero in void `printarray(double **A, int n )` function.

Below my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

void printarray(double **A, int n );

void main(){
double **A;
int n = 3;
int row,col;
double *b;

A = (double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double**));

for (row = 1; row<= n; row++) {
    A[row] = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    }

// Initialize each element.
for (row = 1; row<= n; row++) {
    for (col = 1; col<= n; col++) {
        printf("A[%d][%d]= %u \t",row,col,&A[row][col]);
        scanf("%lf",&A[row][col]);  // or whatever value you want
    }
}

//print A
printf("\n...........array in main.................\n");
for (row = 1; row<= n; row++) {
    for (col = 1; col<= n; col++) {
        printf("A[%d][%d]=%u \t %lf",row,col,&A[row][col],A[row][col]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

b = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));

printf("\n enter the elemet of b \n"); // Initialize each element.
for (row = 1; row<= n; row++){
    printf("address=%u \t",&b[row]);
    printf("b[%d]=",row);
    scanf("%lf",&b[row]);
    printf("\n");
}

printarray((double **)A, n );

}// Print it

void printarray(double **A, int n ){
    int i;
    int j;
    printf("\n.....print a.............\n");
    for( j = 1; j <= n; j++ ){
        for( i = 1; i <= n; i ++){
            printf("A[%d][%d]= %u \t",j,i,&A[j][i]);
            printf( "%lf ", A[j][i] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Post your code here instead of prodiding a link. And what is the problem??

Comment: Indexing starts at 0, not 1. An array of size N should be indexed with values in range 0 to N-1, not 1 to N

Answer (score 1):

One the problem comes from the indexing of your array. Array indexing start at `0`.

This means that in order to loop through your array, you need your `for` loop to start at `0` up to `n-1`:

```
for (int row=0; row<n;++row) {/*...*/}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if i want to start the array indexing from for (int row=1; row<=n;row++) {/*...*/}. but while comparing row<=n , at n=3 its getting out of loop.

Comment: @SnehalP With `for (int row=0; row<n;++row) {/*...*/}` you will not be entering the loop when `n==3`. Basically the notation says "go inside the loop if `row<n` is true. In C array indexing start at 0, this is the way it is. In your case you wan to read A[0], A[1], A[2]. Accessing A[3] will give you unpredictable results.